# Rails Tutorial (M.Hartl) 3rd Edition, Chapter 8, Why does the app fail to forget login status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

After logging into the application and then closing the browser completely, I re-open the browser expecting to be logged-out. However I am still logged in?

I am in section *[8.2.3 Changing the layout links](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-changing_the_layout_links)* and apart from the above, the application looks and runs as expected. Also the code is as it is from the tutorial. I think these are the relevant files:

**app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ordinarily, the `session` is cleared when you close your browser, so you should be logged out automatically in this case. Some browsers remember your session anyway, though, as discussed in [this footnote](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#cha-8_footnote-12), and that could be what's going on here.

Comment: This was helpul. There may be an issue with my Chrome OS browser I think because even after changing settings away from 'Continue where you left off' I get the issue. However using a regular Chrome browser on Windows, this fix works. And IE11 is good too. At least I know I haven't copied your code incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

> After logging into the application and then closing the browser completely, I re-open the browser expecting to be logged-out. However I am still logged in?

Because you are still logged in your application. Your browser remember login data by a cookie used to trace the session.

To log out you can use the logout link explained in the tutorial or you can clean your browser cache.

Comment: The app (thus far) is engineered so that it logs you out automatically upon closing the browser and this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Are you look up the section 8.3? In that section the tutorial explain you how add the logout methods. Without logout methods, you browser cached the sessions.

Comment: See the end of section 8.2.3 and it says:  _"If you quit your browser completely, you should also be able to verify that the application forgets your login status"_

Comment: @Lorenz I think you did not understand the question here. In this application the user will be automatically logged out once you close the browser but it doesn't behave so. You can definitely just click the logout button and do so but question is about the feature that lets user logout after closing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

because you have a cookies, that the way you have like in every page sessions, that's the way are created. They are stored. If you want to deleted, just go to config, delete cookies

Answer (score 0):

According to Mhartl's answer, you will experience the user not being logged out once you close the browser if you are using Chrome (I don't know why exactly) but when you open your application via firefox, user will be logged out automatically (again not sure how) as stated in Chapter 8 .